# Is there a way to script image creation?

Tags: transformations, image

I am facing a though challange - I need to perform repetitive Image formating. Firstly, I need resize picture A so that it has some fixed width in pixels. Then, I need to place picture A in the middle of picture B. I need to perform this task repetitively for hundreds of images. Is there any way to script this, so that I can just type in for example:

```
perform pictureA.png pictureB.png output.png
```

Any help is more than welcome!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org) is a set of command-line tools that can do the sort of things you describe. For example, this command line will overlay picture B with a centered copy of picture A, resized to 100 pixels wide (keeping aspect ratio):

```
convert pictureB.png ( pictureA.png -resize 100 ) -gravity center -composite output.png
```

See [the ImageMagick docs](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-processing.php) for more info about its command lines are structured...it's a powerful piece of software, but it takes a bit of work to get the hang of how to use it.

Comment: Just out of curiosity didnt we agree that [software recommendations are offtopic](http://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)? I dont nesseserily mind but...

Comment: @joojaa The question is about using scripting to automate image operations, which seems on-topic and generally useful to me. Moreover I don't think I should hold back my answer just because it refers to some external software.

Comment: Love you man. You saved so much of my time :) Hope you have a great day!

Comment: No thats not nesseserily what im saying, im just pointing out that have closed questions of simililar nature due to them being software recommendations.

Comment: The question is about a scripting tool, perhaps making it an "API recommendation" question? It would probably be at home in game development. Maybe I've got a meta meta question here - can questions be recommended for transfer to or crossposted on other stack exchange sites?